# Can we assume the last 2 bits of a memory address are 00 and reuse those bits? A windows 7 page fault blue screen

Tags: c++, windows, memory

My friend is programming in c++ on a 64-bit windows 7 PC and he came up with a crazy idea to save a little bit of memory: He observed the last 2 bits of his memory addresses seemed to always be 00, so he figured he could use those bits for other things and then when a memory address is needed, simply use a bit-mask to set the last 2 bits to 0, either when writing or reading memory. The reason why he's only using the last 2 bits is that it needs to work on 32-bit systems too. Anyway, on his Windows 7 64-bit system he got the following blue screen error when running his program:

PAGE_FAULT_IN_NON_PAGED_AREA

Could his crazy memory savings idea be causing this? I.e., can it sometimes happen that the last 2 bits of a memory address are NOT 00, and he's accessing memory that's partly on one of his memory pages, partly off his page? In any event, he needs this to work on ALL popular operating systems. So the question applies to other operating systems as well.

If (in Windows 7 64 bit, at least) his scheme IS guaranteed to work (if coded properly), then what else could be causing the unusual blue screen crash?

Comment: Memory is cheap, the time you spend debugging this is not.

Comment: No, you can't assume addresses are 4-byte aligned (which is what the bottom two bits being zero means) but they often are. Discussion about tagged pointers here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_pointer

Comment: @Jefffrey there are other reasons for wanting to do tagged pointers though. Memory is cheap, accessing it isn't, for example

Comment: Why isn't your friend asking the question? (Could this be an imaginary friend? :-)

Comment: @Amit My friend doesn't have an account, I guess he could create one but I figured I'd just post the question

Comment: @user2566092 - that's ok. just seems odd, but don't take it seriously (see that smiley up there?  here's another one :-)

Comment: It's important to not perform artithmetic directly on pointers.  Is your friend always doing the masking and unmasking on types of `intptr_t`?

Comment: Does "the last 2 bits" mean the *bottom* two bits or the *top* two bits?  Is this a user-mode application or a device driver?

Comment: @HarryJohnston It's the last 2 bits, and not a driver although his company does programming in a weird way so it might be similar to what a driver might do.

Comment: @paddy The arithmetic is being done directly on the pointers being stored as returned by "new" in c++

Comment: The phrase "the last 2 bits" is ambiguous: some people would say that the least significant bits come last, and some people would say that the most significant bits come last.  But I really can't think of any way that tagging a pointer from "new" could cause that particular error, so it probably doesn't matter.

Comment: @HarryJohnston Sorry, I should have clarified. I'm in the camp that always assumes that "last" means least significant. It's least significant 2 bits.

Comment: @Paul How is saving two bits related to the cost of accessing pointers exactly?

Comment: It's hard to imagine how mangled pointers in a user-mode application could result in PAGE_FAULT_IN_NON_PAGED_AREA.  I'd be more inclined to suspect a hardware or device driver problem.

Comment: @jeffrey, if encoding some extra information in the pointer means you don't have to fetch the information from somewhere else.

Comment: I used this trick for almost lock-free intrusive reference counting, allowing up to 4 threads to add/remove ref on a (raw-ish) pointer atomically before blocking occurs (5th thread would spin), without requiring cas of more than a pointer-size.  It solved a practical problem reasonably well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your friend is taking advantage of a feature known as [tagged pointers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_pointer).  On Windows, Raymond Chen has a warning regarding that on his blog:

[There is no /8TB flag on 64-bit Windows](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2015/06/05/10619746.aspx)

> A customer reported that their 64-bit application was crashing on Windows 8.1. They traced the problem back to the fact that the user-mode address space for 64-bit applications on Windows 8.1 is 128TB, whereas it was only 8TB on earlier versions of Windows for x64. ...
>
> ...
>
> As for how they ended up having a dependency on the address space being at most 8TB, they didn't say, but I have a guess: They are using the unused bits for [tagging](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_tagging).
>
> If you are going to use tagged pointers, **you need to put your tag bits in the *least* significant bits, since those are bits you control**. For example, if you align all your objects on 16-byte boundaries, then you have four available bits for tagging. **If you're going to use upper bits for tagging, at least [verify that those upper bits are available](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2014/10/23/10566700.aspx)**.

Something more important to watch out for - a memory pointer allocated by the OS might be aligned in a way that allows for tagging, but if an *intermediate* memory manager sits between the user's code and the OS (which is usually the case), that manager allocates OS memory internally and divides it up for the app to use, so the pointers that the manager gives out to the app might not be aligned in a way that allows for tagging.  You cannot tag any arbitrary memory pointer without knowing where it came from or how it is aligned.

Answer (score 2):

What you're seeing is pointer alignment. On modern computers, objects of size 2/4/8 have addresses which can be divided by 2/4/8. In binary, that means they end with at least 1,2 or 3 zero bits respectively.

Failing to adhere to this rule could crash your application, but not your OS. (Unless you're writing drivers, but then you already know this stuff).
On Windows, however, this error is generally fixed for you.

There could be another issue, though. By modifying the address like that, you shift the object back in memory. If you only allocated 4 bytes, and then move a 4 byte object 3 back (by adding 00000011 to the address), you'll throw away 3 bytes but also use 3 bytes that weren't allocated to your program. Again: program crash, not OS crash. However, Windows won't fix this one.

Comment: Thanks, I guess the windows crash is still a mystery then but at least now I know that we can't always assume the last bits are 0, at least not in a naive way.

Comment: Of course your friend could check the bits in question before converting a raw pointer into a tagged pointer.  There probably wouldn't be anything you can do if the test fails except crash, but at least you'd know *why* you crashed.

Answer (score 1):

Just because malloc/operator new tends to return addresses that are 0 mod 4 or 0 mod 8, does not mean that plenty of other programming circumstances do not end up with pointers that are *not* so. This plan can't work.